# Obtengo el error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 8' al convertir un JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Buenas noches a todos:

Usando este codigo:

```
let a= document.getElementById('main')
    .getAttribute('device')
    .replace(/'/g,"\"");
let b= JSON.parse(a);
```

Estoy tratando de convertir este JSON con javascript:

```
{
  _id: 5e8bf4ed197abf582c0f7584,
  deviceName: "Pycom",
  userOwnerName: "Diego Camilo Peña Ramírez",
  userOwnerId: "5e8a01b81a4df71ba0fe289f",
  token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVlOGEwMWI4MWE0ZGY3MWJhMGZlMjg5ZiIsImlhdCI6MTU4NjIzMDUwOX0.HRpyy1YDhd0lre_vnPnCsbb8tMNpUYYPpd1Z_FVP-nQ",
  temperature: "0",
  humidity: "0",
  date: 2020-04-07T03:35:09.312Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

Pero tengo el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token _ in JSON at position 8
```

Al tratar de convertirlo con JSON.parse.

Alguien podria ayudarme?

Gracias

Comment: Por favor @Diego !!! pon el código donde intentas convertirlo exactamente !!!

Comment: Ya añadí el código

Comment: Uf!! por qué haces ese `.replace(/'/g,"\"");` y de dónde sale el Json exactamente? porque lo que hay en a no parece ser un json, si no más bien un string simplemente, ya que has cogido un atributo. De todos modos, lo que queda en b, es seguro ese json?

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, el replace lo uso para convertir las comillas sencillas en dobles

Comment: me la la sensación que __no es un valor válido en JSON sin hacer escape de esos nombres. De dónde sale el Json??? Es lo que te preguntaba. document.getElementById('main').getAttribute('device') <-- Eso no parece ser algo que pueda tener un Json, y tampoco entiendo el motivo para quitarle las ``` me refiero, tienes claro qué sustitución estás haciendo?

Comment: Si miras la especificación de [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-es.html), verás que tu JSON es inválido: No se aceptan números en formato hexadecimal y una fecha debe ser mandada como un texto (entre comillas)